# Hibernate autoincrement in loadbalancing tomcats?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, load-balancing, auto-increment

I have web application using Hibernate deployed in 3 load balanced Tomcats

and I am frequently getting the following exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:92)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:222)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2224)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:181)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by:
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '145985' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 38 more

And I used the following configuration

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
private Long addressId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IncrementGenerator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/IncrementGenerator.java) is not cluster safe, as documented in the source. It works by reading max id value for the first time and keep increment it in memory. In your case, suppose, at the start, the max value is 10. The IncrementGenerator at 3 nodes may read the value as 10 and assign 11 as the id for the instances created in each node.

Always rely on your database id generation mechanism to be cluster safe.

Comment: how to make sure that db generates the auto increment id in hibernate? if we pass null, hibernate passes null object as the value to the db.

Comment: It depends on your db..for oracle see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384420/how-is-my-id-being-generated-with-jpa-using-hibernate-with-the-oracle-10g-dialec

Comment: In MySql, you can use AUTO_INCREMENT attribute for id columns,http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. Annotate addressId, with @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: Thanks a lot. **GenerationType.AUTO** does the trick what I was looking for.